# How do I create a 10x10 board using PyGame for snakes and ladders?

Tags: python, pygame

I've never used Pygame before but for my project I have decided to create the game 'Snakes & Ladders' it is a board game with usually around 100 squares and has counters/pieces for the users. It has a die you roll to control how many spaces you move, if the you land on a ladder, it will take you to a certain position ahead of where you already are, if you land on a snake it will take you to a position behind of where you currently are. It is usually played with 2-4 players.

I was wondering, how would I be able to create a numbered 10*10 grid using Pygame, as I have no experience with it, I've done a little research but still don't fully understand.

Answer (score 3):

The first things you should think about is how to seperate your game logic from your drawing logic and how to represent your game state before thinking about something like how to draw a 10*10 grid.

It's actually one of the most important things to do, so let me repeat: think about how to represent your game state first, then think about how to draw it.

Let's say we have a board of 10 tiles (to keep this example simple), so let's start by creating a map that connects the tiles:

```
CONNECTIONS = {
    2: 4,
    1: 7,
    5: 3,
    8: 0,
}
```

This means that if a player lands on tile 2, they move to tile 4. If they land on tile 8, they move back to 0, etc. So `CONNECTIONS` is already an important part of out game.

Since we want a nice board to play on, let's define where each tile is located on the screen. We can use a simple list for that:

```
POSITIONS = [
    (93, 394),
    (244, 338),
    (368, 391),
    (457, 317),
    (579, 348),
    (572, 181),
    (458, 108),
    (379, 203),
    (231, 115),
    (89, 197)
]
```

This means tile 0 is at the screen positon `(93, 394)` etc. and already allows us to draw a nice game board using pygame's `draw` module

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
...
# Let's create a board
board = screen.copy()
board.fill((40, 40, 40))

# We connect all dots with lines
prev = None
for pos in POSITIONS:
    if prev:
        pygame.draw.line(board, (0,0,0), prev, pos, 4)
    prev = pos

# Then we draw the good and bad connections
for pos in CONNECTIONS:
    target = CONNECTIONS[pos]
    pygame.draw.line(board, (0,200,0) if pos < target else (200,0,0), POSITIONS[pos], POSITIONS[target], 4)

# Last we create all fields
for pos in POSITIONS:
    pygame.draw.circle(board, (0,0,0), pos, 40)
    pygame.draw.circle(board, (200,200,200), pos, 36)
```

[image]

and to reuse `CONNECTIONS` and `POSITIONS` later (green is good, red is bad).

Of course, if you want a simple grid instead of an asymetric board, you can just use a nested loop or some simple math to create the position of each tile on the fly.

But as you can see, we already have some kind of relation between the game coordinate (which is 1D: the board is linear) and the screen coordinate (which is 2D: x and y), and that these things are different.

That means that if we use some data structure to represent the player, that data structure (we'll use a class that subclasses pygame's `Sprite`), should also have two positions: one that represents the position of the player on the board, and one that represents the position of the sprite on the field.

When the player moves, we change its board position, and if they land on a field that has a connection (we compare their board position with the values in `CONNECTIONS`), we know that the player has to move on.

So here's an example I hacked together (press any key to roll the die and move):

```
import pygame
import random

CONNECTIONS = {
    2: 4,
    1: 7,
    5: 3,
    8: 0,
}

POSITIONS = [
    (93, 394),
    (244, 338),
    (368, 391),
    (457, 317),
    (579, 348),
    (572, 181),
    (458, 108),
    (379, 203),
    (231, 115),
    (89, 197)
]

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
        self.image.fill((200,100,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # The player has a state.
        # Either it is WAITING, so it reacts to the move() command
        # Or it is already MOVING, and pressing a key does nothing
        self.state = 'WAITING'

        # It's important to have a distinction between the logical position
        # on the board, and the actual position of the sprite on the screen
        # We start on board position 0
        self.board_pos = 0

        # We set the current position of the sprite to the position
        # of the tile we're standing on
        self.rect.center = POSITIONS[self.board_pos]

        # We use an additional vector to store the position of the
        # sprite so we can let pygame handle all the vector math
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.center)

    def move(self):
        if self.state == 'WAITING':
            # If we are waiting and a key is pressed, we start moving
            eyes = random.randint(1, 6)
            print(f"rolled a {eyes}")
            # Keep track of how many tiles we move forward
            self.eyes = eyes
            self.state = 'MOVING'
            # Since we move forward, increase our board position
            self.board_pos += 1
            # We want a smooth movement, so we store the position
            # of the next tile in a vector, too
            self.target = pygame.Vector2(POSITIONS[self.board_pos])

    def update(self, dt, events):
        if self.state == 'MOVING':
            # When we're moving, create a movement vector 
            # so we know in which direction we have to move
            movement = self.target - self.pos
            length = movement.length()

            if length < 5:
                # We arrived at out target tile

                # If we still have some tiles to go, decrease the number
                # since we arrived at one
                if self.eyes > 0:
                    self.eyes -= 1

                self.pos = self.target
                if self.eyes == 0:
                    # We moved all tiles, so let's see if there's a 
                    # connection to another tile
                    con = CONNECTIONS.get(self.board_pos, None)
                    if con:
                        # If there is, we have a new target to move to 
                        self.board_pos = con
                        self.target = pygame.Vector2(POSITIONS[self.board_pos])
                    else:
                        # If not, our turn is over
                        self.state = 'WAITING'
                else:
                    # We have still some tiles to go
                    self.board_pos += 1
                    self.target = pygame.Vector2(POSITIONS[self.board_pos])
            else:
                # Just keep moving
                movement.normalize_ip()
                # Some math to keep the movement smooth and nice
                self.pos += movement * dt/10 * max(length/40., 0.7)

        # Pygame uses the rect attribute to position the sprite
        # so let's update it with the position of our vector
        self.rect.center = int(self.pos.x), int(self.pos.y)

def main():
    width, height = 640, 480
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    player = Player()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

    # Let's create a board
    board = screen.copy()
    board.fill((40, 40, 40))

    # We connect all dots with lines
    prev = None
    for pos in POSITIONS:
        if prev:
            pygame.draw.line(board, (0,0,0), prev, pos, 4)
        prev = pos

    # Then we draw the good and bad connections
    for pos in CONNECTIONS:
        target = CONNECTIONS[pos]
        pygame.draw.line(board, (0,200,0) if pos < target else (200,0,0), POSITIONS[pos], POSITIONS[target], 4)

    # Last we create all fields
    for pos in POSITIONS:
        pygame.draw.circle(board, (0,0,0), pos, 40)
        pygame.draw.circle(board, (200,200,200), pos, 36)

    dt = 0
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                player.move()

        screen.blit(board, (0,0))
        sprites.update(dt, events)
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]